`solana-transaction-status` and `solana-sdk` edge incompatibility
In my project, I'm trying to use the edge versions of both solana-sdk and solana-program-test. However, I get the following error.
    Updating crates.io index
    Updating git repository `https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave`
error: failed to select a version for `curve25519-dalek`.
    ... required by package `solana-program v2.0.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `solana-program = "^2.0.0"` of package `spl-associated-token-account v4.0.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `spl-associated-token-account = "=4.0.0"` of package `solana-transaction-status v2.1.0 (https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave?rev=f9f8b60#f9f8b60c)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `solana-transaction-status` of package `solana-runtime v2.1.0 (https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave?rev=f9f8b60#f9f8b60c)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `solana-runtime` of package `solana-program-test v2.1.0 (https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave?rev=f9f8b60#f9f8b60c)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `solana-program-test` of package `example-script v0.1.0 (/Users/yuwenzhang/groth16-solana/example/script)`
versions that meet the requirements `^3.2.1` are: 3.2.1

all possible versions conflict with previously selected packages.

  previously selected package `curve25519-dalek v3.0.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `curve25519-dalek = "^3"` of package `ed25519-dalek v1.0.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `ed25519-dalek = "=1.0.1"` of package `solana-sdk v2.1.0 (https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave?rev=f9f8b60#f9f8b60c)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `solana-sdk` of package `example-script v0.1.0 (/Users/yuwenzhang/groth16-solana/example/script)`

failed to select a version for `curve25519-dalek` which could resolve this conflict

Is this a user error? Why can't I just import two different versions of curve25519-dalek?
EDIT: This also happens when I try to import solana-validator and solana-test-validator, as well as solana-program-test.
EDIT2: Solved, had to add these to my Cargo.toml.

# See https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/master/Cargo.toml#L551-L586
solana-curve25519 = { git = "https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave", rev = "6e62af0f0de6a40e4e22628cbbcf63b1a6da560e"}
solana-program = { git = "https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave", rev = "6e62af0f0de6a40e4e22628cbbcf63b1a6da560e"}
solana-bn254 = { git = "https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave", rev = "6e62af0f0de6a40e4e22628cbbcf63b1a6da560e" }
solana-zk-sdk = { git = "https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave", rev = "6e62af0f0de6a40e4e22628cbbcf63b1a6da560e" }
solana-zk-token-sdk = { git = "https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave", rev = "6e62af0f0de6a40e4e22628cbbcf63b1a6da560e"}


You'll likely need to patch the solana-sdk crate in your Cargo.toml to make this work properly. Try adding the following to force all your dependencies to also use the 2.1 dependencies:
[patch.crates-io]
solana-program = { git = "https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave" }
solana-zk-token-sdk = { git = "https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave" }

Solution adapted from https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/master/Cargo.toml
